# css perspective property not working on firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, css-transforms

I'm trying to make a list of book covers with css. Here is my html:

```
<div class="books">
  <div class="book verde" ><img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png" /></div><br>
  <div class="book verde" ><img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png" /></div><br>
  <div class="book verde" ><img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png" /></div><br>
  <div class="book verde" ><img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png" /></div><br>
  <div class="book verde" ><img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png" /></div><br>
  <div class="book verde" ><img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png" /></div><br>
</div>
```

And here my most relevant css:

```
.csstransforms3d  .books {
  -moz-perspective: 100px;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.csstransforms3d  .book {
  position: relative;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-3deg);
  outline: 1px solid transparent; 
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: -webkit-transform ease-in-out .5s;
  -o-transition: transform ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s;
  transition: transform ease-in-out .5s, -webkit-transform ease-in-out .5s;
}
```

This works fine on chrome but firefox shows a wrong perspective.

I realised that in firefox the perspective changes if I move one element to another position.

If I make a different containers for every simple book the problem seems to dissapear although perspective appearence is different from chrome's and I think this solution is really bad:

```
<div class="books">
  <div class="book verde" ><img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png" /></div><br>
</div>
<div class="books">
  <div class="book verde" ><img src="https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/01/children_bookcover.png" /></div><br>
</div>
```

Feel free to see my full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/fyhh8v73/5/ (just a container) https://jsfiddle.net/rkejgkzy/3/ (a container for every book)